# I wanna make an algorithm to show an state of hanoi tower

Tags: python, algorithm

I wanna make an algorithm to show an state of hanoi tower.
There are 3 piles & 3 disks(A is smallest disk,B is middle one,C is biggest one) and when I move disks for 4 times that my ideal algorithm is to show  an state of hanoi tower.For example,I wanna show

```
- 　（1st pile)
B A （2nd pile)
C   （3rd pile)
```

- means there is no disk.
Now my code is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def hanoi(n, x, y, z,count):
  while count < 4:
    count += 1
    if count != 1:
        count += 1
        hanoi(n-1, x, z, y,count)
        count += 1
        hanoi(n-1, z, y, x,count)
  return "{}→{}".format(x, y)

x = hanoi(3, "A", "C", "B",0)
print(x)
```

But this codes' result is `A→C` so it means next hand auditor.How can I fix to print out  my ideal result?How can I write this?

Comment: I don't understand the question: are the arguments `(3, "A", "C", "B",0)` supposed to show the result you show in your first code block? How does the input map to the result?

Comment: `hanoi` calls itself recursively, but doesn't use the result. The `return` is always just the `x` and `y` values that were passed in: in your example's case, `A` and `C`.

Comment: In relation to　(3, "A", "C", "B",0),3 means there are 3 piles , "A"&"C"& "B" are 3 disks.Yes...,I cannot know how to show an state of hanoi tower.You r right,in my code,always A and C are in the result.So,if u know to do my ideal result,please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a faster algorithm than to go through all the moves one by one. There is a formula to know where a disc is at a certain move.

Since your disc names are quite fixed (A, B, C....), I would not provide that as argument, but let the the function assume the smallest is A, then B, then C, ... up to the number you provide as argument.

```
def hanoi_pos(discs, index):
    power = 2**discs
    stacks = ['>', '>', '>']
    for disc in range(discs):
        stack = (index+power//2)//power % 3
        if disc % 2 == 0: stack = (3 - stack) % 3
        power = power // 2
        stacks[stack] += chr(64 + discs - disc)
    return '\n'.join(stacks)

print(hanoi_pos(3, 4)) # State when there are 3 discs, after 4 moves.
```

This will print:

```
>
>BA
>C
```

You could even produce all consecutive states like this:

```
for i in range(8):
    print(hanoi_pos(3, i))
    print()
```

Output:

```
>CBA
>
>

>CB
>
>A

>C
>B
>A

>C
>BA
>

>
>BA
>C

>A
>B
>C

>A
>
>CB

>
>
>CBA
```

#### Explanation

The expression `chr(64 + discs - disc)` determines what the name is of the disc with number `disc`. The biggest disc will have number 0. Its name depends on the number of discs. If there are three discs, then the name of disc 0 will be 'C', but if there are four, then it will be 'D'. So the more discs there are the higher the ASCII code of the first disc. This is why there is `+ discs`. Any next disc will be the predecessor of that name, so going backwards in the alphabet. That is why there is `- disc`. Finally, 64 is the ASCII code of the character that precedes 'A'. Since `discs - disc` will be at least 1, the lowest ASCII code will be 65, which converts to character 'A'.

Comment: thx!I have a question,I cannot understand this code's meaning 
stacks[stack] += chr(64 + discs - disc)  .

Comment: Why do u  do discs - disc?

Answer (score 0):

I think an array of arrays would be a good way to store your game state:

```
# example data
pegs = [[], ['B', 'A'], ['C']]
```

Then a concise method could convert your game state to a readable string:

```
def get_game_state(pegs):
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(peg) if peg else '-' for peg in pegs])
```

(if you are a Python beginner and need help understanding the above line, look up list comprehensions, ternary operator, and str's `join` method)

```
print(get_game_state(pegs))
```

Example output:

```
-
B A
C
```

Comment: thx.In my case,3 disks are designated,so how can I get pegs array when I move disks for 4 times ?I wanna make this algorithm can correspond  to the time when I move disks for 3 times & 5 times &etc.